# Django dynamic views based on dropdwon option

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I have created an app that collect all daily income. The model is the following:

```
class Income(models.Model):
        date=models.DateField('', default="GG/MM/YYYY")
        income=models.DecimalField()
```

I have created a simple template that contains the form and the data table with all data collected.

```
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
h5>Income data collection</h5>
<div class="row">
             <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                 {{form.income|as_crispy_field}}
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                 {{form.date|as_crispy_field}}
             </div>
  </div>
        <table class="table" >           
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Income</th>
              <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {% for inc in income%}
              <tr>
                  <td>{{inc.income}}</td>
                  <td>{{inc.date}}</td>                  
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the views I have added the following filter:

```
income=Income.objects.filters(data__year='2020')
```

At this point, I have created another model that set the reference year as the following:

I have the following model

```
class Timing(models.Model):
    reference_year=models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default="2020")
```

This model have a view with form that give to the client the possibility to register all reference year (2020, 2021 and so on). Now I want to link `reference_year` with `income` views.py. How? with a dropdown menu that cointains all reference_year filled. 
So for example if clients save in timing models a reference_year equal to 2020, in the dropdown the client could select it and the views dynamically update the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you should save the data by an ajax function and then edit the dropdown menu from within ajax success function. In the view side get the existing data and send it to html. Sorry I can't comment since my reputation is below 50. If that's what you are looking for I can explain it in a more detailed way.

Comment: Yes would be great if you could explain me with an example.

Comment: I have created a form to fill the Timing db. So I want to create in my template a dropdown select menu that give me the possibility to select the year and after that update my table views changing the `income=Income.objects.filters(year='reference_year')`

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not  referance Timing as a foreign key in your Income model?

Comment: Sorry I understand that my question was incomplete. So I have edited it with all details

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it at all. Do you want every user to have an unique income model? If so do you want every income model to have a default date and change it only if the user selects another date from drop down list? Why do you need another model just for dates, why don't you just generate them in the view?